# how does situation of two studios releasing similar movies occur?

Tags: production

- Armageddon and Deep Impact
- Dante's Peak and Volcano
- Wyatt Earp and Tombstone

I'm certain there are more examples, those are just the ones that came right to mind.  But how is that that separate studios will release similar movies in a close time frame to one another?

this is a question that has often caused me some deep thought.

Comment: I post it as a comment because it does not match the examples, but there is a classic case : the source material goes public (we had the situation in France a few years ago with 'La guerre des boutons')

Comment: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/46797/why-are-two-jungle-book-movies-being-made-consecutively + https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/88785/two-magician-films-released-nearly-the-same-time-any-connection/ + https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/12376/similarities-of-pixar-and-dreamworks-any-published-explanation